# Xcode 7 - WebView app not in fullscreen displayed

Tags: swift, webview, fullscreen, xcode7, ios-web-app

I've been working on a webview app, and it runs just fine other than the fact that the app is not being displayed fullscreen but in the top left corner (see image).
Does anyone know if this is some sort of setting for the screen?

Any help on the matter would be much appreciated
[image]

Comment: It has nothing to do with XCode 7. Check your constraints.

Comment: If you want to have your application fullscreen set 4 constraints and set them to 0... Look that you uncheck the tick "constraints to margin"

if you also want to remove the statusbar for a full screen then use this `UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = true
` in the viewDidLoad

Comment: That one did the trick, thanks a lot!